# Can VS Code compile classes automatically in the background like the Dev Console?

Tags: vs-code, compile

The online Dev Console automatically compiles every few seconds and checks for any kind of undefined variable, but in VS Code you can type all kinds of jibberish that won't throw any errors in the console, even with the Apex extensions. It seems like one of the biggest shortcomings to the product that Salesforce is pushing for developers. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This extension has configurable rules and does static code analyze of your apex code. Can be configured to run every time you save the class (not deploy).

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-pmd

Comment: Thanks, good to know, but this still does not appear to compile the class against the relevant SF environment.